# Print new line in Google app engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, newline, new-operator

```
self.response.out.write("\n")
```

When i upload a data of multiline using text property and then printing it back it prints in a single line....
i upload the ascii hexa code ....
so carriage return is 0x10 but when pringing it in ascii from datastore the new line is not inserted...
instead it prints as a single line

```
import cgi
#import codecs
print 'Content-Type: text/plain'
print ''
print 'Hello, world!'

from google.appengine.ext import webapp
from google.appengine.ext.webapp.util import run_wsgi_app
from google.appengine.ext import db

import operator

class Vault(db.Model):
    username=db.StringProperty()
    filename=db.StringProperty()
    data=db.TextProperty()

op=""
op1=""
username=""
filename=""


class MainPage(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        stri=""
        global username
        global filename
        stri=""
        username = self.request.get("name")
        filename=self.request.get("filename")
        mac=self.request.get("mac")
        mac=mac.replace(':','')
        q=db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Vault WHERE filename=:1",filename)
        for vault in q:
            stri=cgi.escape(vault.data)
        s=0
        e=12
        cycle=len(stri)/12
        z=""
        for j in range(cycle):
            plain=stri[s:e]
            #print plain
            s1=0
            s2=2
            for i in range(6):
                x=int(plain[s1:s2],16)
                y=int(mac[s1:s2],16)
                s1=s1+2
                s2=s2+2
                z+=chr(operator.xor(x,y))
            mac=plain
            s=s+12
            e=e+12
        print z

application = webapp.WSGIApplication([('/dec', MainPage)],debug=True)

def main():
    run_wsgi_app(application)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Please, please don't use `print` in a WSGI app. Use `self.response.out.write`, never `print`. The statements up the top of your code won't do what you think they will, either.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Where are you printing that data back out to? If it's inside of HTML (well, unless it's surrounded by `<pre>` tags), the newlines will be ignored regardless of whether the EOL is indicated by `\n` or `\r\n`.

If that's what's going on, you can just do

```
self.response.out.write(myString.replace("\n", "<br />"))
```

Comment: @bgporter:i'm encrypting the data and store the hex ascii values in datastore. when i decrypt the hex to ascii and print it using self.response.out.write(z) [where z cantains the decrypted ascii values] it prints in a straight line....

Comment: @HariHaraSudhan That shouldn't matter, unless your unencrypt function is somehow broken. As @Hugh suggests in his response -- look at the response using your browser's View Source. If it looks right there, your browser is interpreting the contents as HTML, which ignores newline characters. You can set the Content-type header for your reply to `text/plain` to force the issue.

Comment: @HariHaraSudhan - are you setting the response's content type to text/plain?

Comment: @bgporter&wooble: I did that , but when i try for first time after saving the python file, its giving the line break. after the when i request again, it goes back to same onld single line style

Comment: Your lines of code that add the initial headers are only executed the first time that this module is imported by GAE. Move those down inside the `get()` method.

Comment: @bgporter: Thats absolutely gr8!!!!!!!   Thanks a lot :)   .......But i also have the doubt why the initial part not within the class are executed only the fisrt time....wasn't the code to be executed everytime it gets the url???

Comment: No -- in Python, code that's outside of functions or methods will only be executed when that module is imported. Making things more confusing in this instance is that you can't predict when this will happen to your code -- if your app gets accessed on the same server where it's still in memory, the server won't need to reimport it. On a different server or if the server frees your app from memory, it will. Anything that you want to happen per-request needs to be in a get()/post() handler.

Answer (score 3):

In your web browser, try looking at the result using 'View page source'.

If the line-breaks look correct there, then @bgporter has the correct solution.

Comment: When the data is written to a file or if the page source is viewed the line break is seen.... but in the html page its not seen